# Erro ao cadastrar usuário no Ajax Quick Checkout FREE opencart

Tags: php, opencart, checkout

Boas, estou tentando instalar o Ajax Quick Checkout FREE em minha loja opencart 3.0, e estou tendo o seguinte problema, vejam se podem me ajudar:

A instalação corre normalmente, vou ao modo front-end e testar o Ajax Quick Checkout se tento fazer a compra sem criar conta, ele funciona perfeitamente, mas se vou para criar conta ele gera a conta, mas não efetiva a venda!

E só retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at Object.validate (d_quickcheckout.min.js:295)
at Object._validate (backbone-min.js:1)
at Object.set (backbone-min.js:1)
at Object.set (d_quickcheckout.min.js:5)
at d_quickcheckout.min.js:301
at Function.m.each.m.forEach (underscore-min.js:5)
at s.update (d_quickcheckout.min.js:300)
at p (backbone-min.js:1)
at g (backbone-min.js:1)
at l (backbone-min.js:1)

payment_address:render
field:render
shipping_address:render
field:render
```

Imagem de não criar conta: FUNCIONA
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem para criar conta: NÃO FUNCIONA
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Obrigado!

Comment: Olá! Por favor, forneça o erro em formato texto. Mostrando apenas a imagem com o texto do erro fica mais difícil entender o que ocorre e as pessoas que tiverem o mesmo erro não vão conseguir encontrar sua pergunta, no futuro, para saber qual a solução :)

Comment: Alterada @Dherik